# regex remove_punctuation, but keep AT single(double) uppercase - char(s) dot

Tags: python, regex

i need remove punctuation, but keep at Single Uppercase char a dot (If its part of human Name:) : for ex.: in this string:

```
Michigan State President Samuel L. Stanley Jr. and Interim Provost Teresa Sullivan hosted a webinar Friday night, answering questions from returning MSU students.
```

I need to keep dots  at `L.  Jr.`

this will be delete all punctuation:

```
text = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s\n]+', '', text)
```

Comment: Your regex deletes more than punctuation, it will remove my `Виктор` name entirely

Comment: ou thanks for the point but, i work with english right now

Comment: If you need to remove any punctuation but after some specific words, use `re.sub(r'\b((?:L|Jr)\.)|[^\s\w]+', r'\1', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5F4ELu/1). Add more words to the `(?:L|Jr)` group if you need.

Comment: ok, but (?:L|Jr), it can be any kind of the char not only these specific, in my case

Comment: So, what kind of char? What is the pattern you want to avoid removing? `[A-Z][a-z]?` `r'\b([A-Z][a-z]?\.)|[^\s\w]+'`

Comment: the capital single letter (A-Z ) for example: P.    OR  2 char world: the first is capital  letter and second not (A-Z ), for example: Jr.

Comment: `re.sub(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]?\.)|[^\s\w]+', r'\1', text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
text = re.sub(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]?\.)|_|[^\s\w]+', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5F4ELu/3)

**Details**

- `\b([A-Z][a-z]?\.)` - word boundary, then a Group 1: an uppercase followed witg a lowercase letter and then a dot (`\1` in the replacement pattern restores this text in the result, so that this matched part is not removed from the string)
- `|` - or
- `_` - an underscore
- `|` - or
- `[^\s\w]+` - 1 or more chars other than letters, digits, `_` and whitespace.